# Background image not show fully on mobile's

Tags: html, css

body background image is not showing on mobile height wise. It show on half of the body. image size is (1600*1050)

Here is Css code

```
body {
    background:url('img/dot.png') repeat, url('img/bg2.jpg') center fixed no-repeat;
    background-size:auto, cover;
    min-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Kindly advice me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background height and width 100%

`background-size: 100% 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove auto from background-size, like this:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I have two background image on body. If I have changed auto to cover background will be disturb.this image img/dot.png(only one pixel dot) show as a whole black color.

Comment: I see. Please try this one if it helps: background-size:auto, contain;